# juntar duas tabelas com condição de data

Tags: sql, data

Preciso juntar duas tabelas, sendo a primeira apresentando todos os registros contido nela, com a condição de o que estiver na segunda tabela tem um preço menor com `data_ini` e `dt_fim` usando o `current_date` para definir se esta dentro da condição ou seja, dentro da data vigente.

Exemplo:

Tabela 1:

```
---------------+------------+------
cod_barras     | descrição  | preco
---------------+------------+------
00000000000017 | PAO DE SAL |  0,50
00000000000122 | PEPSI 1 5L |  5,00
00000000000987 | TAIOBA     |  2,00
00000000001526 | ALHO KG    | 20,00
```

Tabela 2:

```
---------------+-------+------------+-----------
barras         | preco | DT_ini     | DT_FIM
---------------+-------+------------+-----------
00000000000017 |  0,30 | 03/11/2017 | 10/11/2017
00000000001526 | 15,00 | 05/11/2017 | 08/11/2017
```

Considerando que a `current_date` = 04/11/2017, deveria ficar assim:

```
---------------+------------+------
cod_barras     | descrição  | preco
---------------+------------+------
00000000000017 | PAO DE SAL |  0,30
00000000000122 | PEPSI 1 5L |  5,00
00000000000987 | TAIOBA     |  2,00
00000000001526 | ALHO KG    | 20,00
```

Considerando que a `current_date` = 07/11/2017, deveria ficar assim:

```
---------------+------------+------
cod_barras     | descrição  | preco
---------------+------------+------
00000000000017 | PAO DE SAL |  0,30
00000000000122 | PEPSI 1 5L |  5,00
00000000000987 | TAIOBA     |  2,00
00000000001526 | ALHO KG    | 15,00
```

Considerando que a `current_date` = 11/11/2017, deveria ficar assim:

```
---------------+------------+------
cod_barras     | descrição  | preco
---------------+------------+------
00000000000017 | PAO DE SAL |  0,50
00000000000122 | PEPSI 1 5L |  5,00
00000000000987 | TAIOBA     |  2,00
00000000001526 | ALHO KG    | 20,00
```

Ou seja, preciso que um item que exista na tabela 2 dentro de uma data específica pegar o preço da tabela 2 e não da tabela 1.

Vai pegar o valor da tabela 1, se não estiver contido na tabela 2 e dentro da data vigente.

Quem puder ajudar, está um pouco difícil.

Comment: Consegue passar isso no SQL Fiddle ? http://sqlfiddle.com/
 Assim conseguiríamos simular com mais facilidade aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um left outer join colocando as condições no join, e utilize o coalesce para os produtos que não tem registros correspondentes na tabela2:

```
Select
p.cod_barras,
p.descricao,
coalesce(t.preco,p.preco) as preco
from tabela1 p 
left outer join tabela2 t
                on p.cod_barras = t.barras 
                and t.dt_ini <= current_date 
                and t.dt_fim >= current_date
                and t.preco < p.preco --(Só vai buscar na segunda tabela se o preço for menor certo ? caso contrário, só tirar essa linha)
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/410ec0/2

Comment: boa tarde,  obrigado... deu certo.... valeu mesmo...

Comment: @sreletronica não se esqueça de avaliar a questão e marcar como resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

quando fizer o join, não faz direto na tabela filtra antes, ai fica mais facil;

por exemplo

```
 select*from produto a
 join (select cod_barras, min(valor) valor
           from produtos_preco  
              where data_final>data_atual 
                and data_inicia<data_atual
                group by cod_barras) b on a.cod_barras =b.cod_barras
```

um coisa assim, pelo que eu intendi;
mas achei meio difícil de intender a pergunta :)